# Error installing psycopg2 while connecting to postgreSQL db

Tags: python, postgresql, macos-big-sur

I'm trying to write a code in python which would connect to PostgreSQL and do basic CRUD operations.

The sample code I'm following is importing psycopg2. I tried importing that module via PyCharm and that failed then I tried doing that via Terminal within IDE and it is providing me the error as below:

```
gcc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -arch x86_64 -g build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_asis.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_binary.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_list.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_pint.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/aix_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/bytes_format.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/column_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/connection_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/conninfo_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/cursor_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/error_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/green.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/libpq_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/lobject_int.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/lobject_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/microprotocols.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/notify_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/pqpath.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/replication_connection_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/replication_cursor_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/replication_message_type.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/solaris_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/typecast.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/utils.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/win32_support.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg/xid_type.o -L/usr/local/lib -lpq -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.9/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-39-darwin.so
    ld: library not found for -lssl
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: '/Users/mukul/PycharmProjects/Test Assignment/venv/bin/python' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/jf/psd6t3h92zv4dlsskwfq4jvm0000gn/T/pip-install-sesoe_u_/psycopg2_3dea34ab36b9473db07298279bce13e5/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/jf/psd6t3h92zv4dlsskwfq4jvm0000gn/T/pip-install-sesoe_u_/psycopg2_3dea34ab36b9473db07298279bce13e5/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/jf/psd6t3h92zv4dlsskwfq4jvm0000gn/T/pip-record-z7u8cdcp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers '/Users/mukul/PycharmProjects/Test Assignment/venv/include/site/python3.9/psycopg2' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Can anyone please help me with this?
I have already tried installing the latest version of the xcode command tool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not look like you are importing  but building/installing `psycopg2`. Is that the case?

Comment: I'm trying to connect PostgreSQL via python code. and I find a sample code that needs this importing, but my IDE says, install it first. During pip install psycopg2, I'm facing this issue.

Comment: A regular `pip install psycopg2` is going to need associated development libraries to compile the code. You need to either install development libraries or do `pip install psycopg2-binary` which installs a pre-compiled binary. For potential issues with this see [Install](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html#quick-install) psycopg vs psycopg-binary.